# select box's heights grows in ie7 issue

Tags: html, css, select

hi guys im experiencing a problem while building up a form with label, input and select fields.
what i want is to have them all on a single line(vertical-aligned middle,inside a container DIV),all of them with same height and possibly style the border for all of them.

i achieve all of this in firefox an IE8 but if i switch to compatibility mode i have:

1. -select boxes grows their heights
2. -select boxes lose the border style I applied (1px solid red)
3. -labels and selects then shifts down to align their top borders with the inputs ones

why is this happening how can I solve that ?
thanks
Luca

that-s the code! =)

```
<div class="searcher" >
    <form>
        from:<input type="text" value="2011/02/22" />
        <input type="image" src="../img/cal.png"  width="16px" height="16px" style="vertical-align:middle;"/>
        to:<input type="text" value="2011/02/22" />

        <select style="width:110px;border:1px solid #F60;vertical-align:middle;">
          <option value="">sport</option>
          <option value="">gastronomy</option>
          <option value="">art&culture</option>
          <option value="">leisure</option>
          <option value="" selected="selected">All categories</option>
</select>
<select name="" style="width:90px">
        <option value="" selected="selected">Rome</option>
</select>
<a href="">search!</a>
       </form>
    </div>

/*AND CSS*/
html, body, span,a, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5,div, h6,  
p,blockquote,pre, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins,  
kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, 
dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead,tr,
th,input, td {border: 0 none;margin: 0;padding: 0;}

html{overflow:auto;}

.searcher{float:left;height:38px;width:610px;padding:6px 15px 8px 15px;margin:30px 15px 0 0;}

body{font:13px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;cursor:default;padding:0; font-weight:bold;}
form{display:inline;}
```

Comment: What select boxes, where's your form? I don't see any code! :D Please post some code so we can take a closer look at your problem :)

Comment: and start to accept some answers on your previous questions so that we feel like it is worth answering you in the future. We like to help you but we also like some credit for it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Best this to do would be to use a reset style sheet, like [Eric Meyers](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/), that way it will reset all browsers to the same 'no style', then build up you styles in a separate style sheet.

Comment: i did apply a reset style Alex but if I run the page through IE8 in compatibility mode is like if evertyhing has a kind of extrapadding..maybe i'm missing something

Comment: I notice you have some resetting in your CSS, but have you tried including the reset style sheet? there's loads on there that may effect the padding in IE8